# iOS ViewController doesn't appears although viewDidLoad gets called

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, appdelegate, pushviewcontroller

I'm building an application with different states that need to be restored if a user quits the app for some reason. This means, that different screens/viewcontrollers need to be on top of the navigation stack when the app launching. To achieve this, I tried to build the viewcontrollers programatically, see below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        switch (appState)
        {
            case CSAppStateIdle:
            {
                //replace and push rootview manually
                MainVC* mainView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainVC"];
                [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:mainView animated:YES];
            }
                break;
            case CSAppStateSomeState:
            {
                MainVC* mainView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainVC"];
                SomeVC* someView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeVC"];
                [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController addChildViewController:mainView];
                [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:someView animated:YES];
            }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

I use stroyboards with ID-s set correctly. Well in CSAppStateIdle it works, but in CSAppStateSomeState someView doesn't appear on screen, but in someVC viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and even viewDidAppear gets called.

Has anyone faced this before, or knows the solution? I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `addChildViewController` method call?

Comment: I tried to build a navigation stack, so when a user would push "Back" button from someView and popViewController gets called, then mainView appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put both items on the navigation stack, use the `setViewControllers:animated:` method, passing an array with both items:

```
        case CSAppStateSomeState:
        {
            MainVC* mainView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainVC"];
            SomeVC* someView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeVC"];
            [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController setViewControllers:@[mainView, someView] animated:YES];
        }
```

Comment: This solution works, but the navigationbar disappears from the VC-s, dont't know why yet.

Comment: Is `navigationBarHidden` set to true?

Comment: Well I setted it in the rootVC's viewDidLoad and hoped that it is ok, but it seems to me that i need to set it in every VC's viewDidLoad. Do you have any suggestions on this case? Thanks for the help though!